# Login jsp page with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, session

can i use hibernate to login jsp page using (session)

if i'm not using hibernate i do like this :

```
Username=request.getParameter("UserName");
  Password=request.getParameter("passWord");

  ResultSet s;
ResultSet resultat = stat1.executeQuery("select * from Etudinat where UserName ='"+ Username +"' and Password = '"+Password+"'");

if (resultat.next()) {

  s = stat1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Etudinat where UserName ='"+Username+"'");
  s.next();
  ID = s.getInt("Id_Etudinat");

    session.setAttribute("Id_Etudinat",ID);
    session.setAttribute("UserName",Username);}
```

but with hibernate i want to know this step's:

-when i get the request how can i test the username and password if they exist with hibernate ?

-if they exist do i put them with with `session.setAttribute()` or i can use some thing else with hibernate ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use HQL, which is very similar to SQL. However, always use bound parameter. Like `where username=:username`. Otherwise you risk sql injection. Also, you have to hash your passwords (rather than storing them in plaintext)
- You can place the `User` object that you retrieve in the session.

Comment: thank you sir but how can i hash my passwords ?? and how can i use user and find him on my DB ?

Comment: i try all of them , i dont know how to use a query to find some one and print the result from the query

Comment: HQL is almost the same as SQL. Check the HQL tutorial and you should be able to write it in 5 minutes

Comment: if you use it befor give me the source code plz i cant find how to remplace that ResultSet in hibernate

Comment: I have done it tons of time, but you should learn it as well rather then getting ready-to-use snippets ;)

Comment: hibernateSession.find("select xxx from Etudinat where p.Nom=xxxx"); i'd try this but that give a list and when i try to get data from the list a got an exception ??

Comment: There is no such method as `find()`. There is `createQuery(..)`

Comment: what does the javadoc tell you? There is list() that will execute the query and return a list of objects as a result. I would really advise you to read a hibernate tutorial and try out some examples first.

Comment: thanks i understand now how its work and i did it on my projec thank you again